# unrecognized properties on this 'this' in mongoose virtuals with typegoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, typegoose

I'm trying to define a virtual property on a typegoose model.

```
class foo {
  ...
  start: Date
  end: Date
  get duration(){
    return this.end - this.start
  }
}
```

I get typescript errors that `this` doesn't have the properties `end` or `start`.
Is there a way to make it work properly?

Thanks

Comment: I got a different error: it complains Date Object cannot be substracted directly. Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.1.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBmD29oG8CwAoa0IBcwCccBCALmgBEwcBTAbgy2oDsATUiqujB6Ac2pzQWAV3xUAlvCYAKAJRpMWaPgGim0HAAtxEAHTMWu-jgCy4kCB3VgUlhDnQAtBu17cBHEYFmLVm63tZekUAXwwQoA

Comment: did you already try to manually set the [`this`](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/quick-start-guide#extra-examples) type? (which is always requires in typegoose)

Comment: It seems like it was combination of both, Thanks.